# finite dimension‎‎ space

Tags: real-analysis

Let 
‎‎‏‎$ ‎‎X=C[-1,1]‎$‎‎
be inner product space 
with definition 
‎‎$‎\langle f,g‎‎ ‎\rangle ‎=‎\int‎‎^1_{-1}{f ‎‎\bar{g}‎} ‎dt ‎‎$.‎‎
Let $M$ be the subspace defined by
‎$$ ‎M= ‎‎\lbrace{ f‎  \in ‎X: ‎f(t)=0 ,‎ ( ‎‎-1 \leq‎ t ‎‎\leq ‎0)‎‎\rbrace}. ‎$$

Does $M$ have finite dimension?
thanks

Comment: Can you think of an infinite family of functions in $M$?  Think about graphs of these functions, which lie on the $x$-axis for $x<0$.

Comment: Although only one letter is missing, it took me a while to realize what is meant by "spce".

Comment: You don't need to put an inner product on this to figure out that $M$ has infinite dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Think about the following functions,
$$f_n(x) = \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  x^n  & \mbox{if } x \geq 0 \\
  0 & \mbox{if } x < 0
 \end{array}
\right. \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (n\ge1)
$$